# Constructing a surjective map $S^{n} \rightarrow S^{n}$ of degree zero

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

It is easy to see that if a map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is surjective then its suspension $Sf:SX \rightarrow SY$ is also surjective, and since suspension preserves degree it suffices to construct a map $f:S^{1} \rightarrow S^{1}$ of degree zero and apply repeated suspension to get the maps for $n > 1$.

I am thinking of $S^{1}$ as lying in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and first projecting it onto the $x$-axis followed by identifying the boundary of the of the resulting 1-dimensional disk to a point, I called these maps $p$ and $q$ respectively, so $f=pq$. I chose the point $y\in S^{1}$ which has the $f^{-1}(y)=\{x_{1},x_{2}\}$ as in my picture. The degree of $f$ is the sum of the local degrees at $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$, and the local degree will be $\pm1$ since can choose neighborhoods smartly to get local homeomorphisms at those points.

My intuition tells me that these local degrees should have opposite signs because if we think of the circle has being oriented ccw then neighborhoods around them will project down with orientations in opposite directions.

> How can I justify that their degrees are "opposite" or actually compute the degree?

[image]

Comment: What is your definition of degree ? Since your map factors through an interval, it should be clear that the degree is zero by functoriality of homology/homotopy groups.

Comment: For a map $S^{n} \rightarrow S^{n}$ the induced homomorphism $H_{n}(S^{n}) \rightarrow H_{n}(S^{n})$ is multiplication by an integer $d$, which we define to be the degree of the map.

Comment: Also yes I know that is true, but I was trying to compute it more directly.

Comment: More directly than $f_*=q_*p_*:H_1(S^1)\rightarrow H_1(I)=0\rightarrow H_1(S^1)$ ?

Comment: Maybe I should have said directly using local degrees.

Comment: Ok (that was also the meaning of my question "What is your definition of degree" but I should have been clearer). Well then, the point $(-1;0)$ is a regular value, its preimage consists of the points $(0;1)$ and $(0;-1)$, you can compute whether or not the map preserve orientation at these points (choose local parameters and compute the derivative, this is really easy). Your intuition is indeed correct that one will preserve orientation, and the other won't.

Answer (score 6):

Since i am not a fan of space-filling curves, here is an alternative solution, which generalizes your idea on $S^1$: 
First, project $S^n$ to its southern hemisphere. Then, identify the equator to one point.

Answer (score 5):

First project $S^n$ to an interval $I$. Then compose this projection with a space-filling curve $I \to S^n$.

Comment: why the degree is zero?

Comment: The interval has trivial homology in all degrees above zero.

Comment: Yeah,you’re right.Thanks !